# mousedown event (right click) not working when using hoverIntent

Tags: jquery, mousedown, hoverintent

I'm using the `hoverIntent` with a div like this:

```
$(".mydiv").hoverIntent({    
     sensitivity: 7, 
     interval: 0, 
     over: divHoverOver,
     timeout: 0,
     out: divHoverOut
});
```

`divHoverOver` and `divHoverOut` are two defined functions.
The problem is when I right click on the div, the `divHoverOut` function runs! But I want to run another code when I right click on the div. I have added:

```
$(".mydiv").mousedown(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 3) {
            //do s.th
        }
    });
```

But always `divHoverOut` function is executed!!

Answer (score 1):

For rigth click event binding you must first disable the normal rigth click event by using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};
$(".mydiv").mousedown(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 2) {    // Earlier it was  3 
            //do 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: right click is disabled in this case, nothing is shown when I right click